# Disappearing assigned values of struct components

Tags: go, struct

I am trying to create a list of structures and assign values to components of each structure in the list:

```
package main
import ("fmt";"strconv")
type Mystruct struct{
    code string
    val int
}

var stlist []Mystruct // Need to create this list

func main(){
    //Trying to create list of structures and assigning values: 
    for i,_:=range [3]int{} {
        var st =Mystruct{}
        stlist = append(stlist, st)
        st.val = i
        st.code = "code_"+strconv.Itoa(i)
        fmt.Println("st.code=", st.code, "; st.val=", st.val) // Looks OK. 
    }
    //check values of each item of list: 
    fmt.Println( "-----------------------" )
    for _,e := range stlist{
        fmt.Println("st.code=", e.code, "; st.val=", e.val) // values are blank! Why?
    }
}
```

Above code compiles and runs without any error. However, as mentioned in comments above, although the values seem to be assigned to each component of the list, in second loop, it is found that both components of all structs in the the struct list are blank. The output is:

```
st.code= code_0 ; st.val= 0
st.code= code_1 ; st.val= 1
st.code= code_2 ; st.val= 2
-----------------------
st.code=  ; st.val= 0
st.code=  ; st.val= 0
st.code=  ; st.val= 0
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you pass `st` to `append` a *copy* of the original is appended, because Go is pass by value and not reference, so basically you now have two instances of `Mystruct`, one stored in `st` and another one in `stlist[i]`, therefore updates to the original value won't be visible to the copy inside the slice. Either set the values directly through the slice `stlist[i].val= i`, etc. or use pointers.

Comment: also note that, instead of using `range [N]int{}` when you want to run a loop `N` times, you can use `[N]struct{}{}`, i.e. an array of empty structs, this is because an emtpy struct doesn't take up any memory, whereas an `int` is gonna take up 64 bits, now if you multiply that by `N` you could be inadvertently allocating a lot of memory for no good reason. https://dave.cheney.net/2014/03/25/the-empty-struct

Comment: Very useful points. I would like to see an answer using pointers.

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/Yjv2bLY9PEt

Comment: Very nice. It should be added here as an answer since most users see only answers and not comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in the first loop you append the struct before setting the values so you add an empty struct to the array.

you should put

```
stlist = append(stlist, st)
```

under

```
st.val = i
st.code = "code_"+strconv.Itoa(i)
```

that way you set the values first and then add the struct to your array